# Problema para cargar JS al crear y modificar un elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, php5, html-tabla

Espero puedan apoyarme con estos problemas que tengo con la ejecución de mi `JS`, tengo 2 problemas que detallare:

**AL CREAR**

Estoy usando los eventos de `change` y `select` para poder saber si estoy seleccionando y cambiando una opción de mi `combobox` de preguntas. El problema es cuando tengo seleccionado la opción 1 `RESPUESTA UNICA/MULIPLE` del tipo de pregunta. Si al guardar no tengo seleccionado ningún `checkbox` de las opciones disponibles me arrojara la alerta para seleccionar mínimo una opción, hasta aquí todo me funciona bien pero cuando selecciono un `checkbox` de las opciones e intento guardar, la alerta no desaparece. He intentado agregar el evento `checked` pero no me logra funcionar. Lo que deseo que se realice es que cuando guardo y no tengo una opción seleccionada me arroje el mensaje de alerta (esto ya lo hace), y cuando seleccione una opción me desaparezca la alerta para que me permita guardar.
[image: opción crear]
[image: opción crear 2]

**AL MODIFICAR**

El segundo problema se da cuando intento modificar un elemento, el JS no se ejecuta, para que pueda funcionar tengo que seleccionar otra opción y regresar a la anterior para que recién pueda funcionar.
[image: opción modificar]
[image: opción modificar 2]

**CÓDIGO JS**

Este es el código que utilizo.

```
$(".form_preguntas").on("change","select",function(){     
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    var justificar=id.match(/^([a-zA-Z]+)\-([0-9]+)/g)[0]+'-justificar_respuesta';
    var index = $(this).attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    var index_pregunta = index.substring(0,1); 
    var index_opcion = index.substring(1,2);
    var index_fix = index_pregunta+'-'+index_opcion;
    if ($(this).val()== 2) {
        $('#'+justificar).hide();
        $("label[for='" + justificar + "']").hide();
        $('#'+index_pregunta).find('.opcion-item').not(':first').remove();
        $('#'+index_pregunta).find('.opcion-item:first').hide(); 
        $('#'+index_pregunta).find('.item-opcion').hide(); 
        $('#'+index_pregunta).find('.pregunta').attr('colspan',2);
    }else if ($(this).val()== 1){
        var newtr =         '<tr class="opcion-item">';
        newtr = newtr +         '<td class="vcenter">';
        newtr = newtr +             '<div class="input-group">';
        newtr = newtr +                 '<span class="input-group-addon">';
        newtr = newtr +                     '<div class="form-group field-evaopcion-'+index_pregunta+'-0-opcion_correcta required">';
        newtr = newtr +                         '<div class="checkbox">';
        newtr = newtr +                             '<label style="padding:5px;" for="evaopcion-'+index_pregunta+'-0-opcion_correcta">';
        newtr = newtr +                                 '<input type="hidden" name="EvaOpcion['+index_pregunta+'][0][opcion_correcta]" value="0">';
        newtr = newtr +                                 '<input type="checkbox" id="evaopcion-'+index_pregunta+'-0-opcion_correcta" name="EvaOpcion['+index_question+'][0][opcion_correcta]" value="1">';
        newtr = newtr +                             '</label>';
        newtr = newtr +                             '<p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>';
        newtr = newtr +                         '</div>';
        newtr = newtr +                      '</div>';                    
        newtr = newtr +                 '</span>';
        newtr = newtr +                 '<div class="form-group field-evaopcion-'+index_pregunta+'-0-titulo_opcion required">';
        newtr = newtr +                     '<input type="text" id="evaopcion-'+index_pregunta+'-0-titulo_opcion" class="form-control" name="EvaOpcion['+index_question+'][0][titulo_opcion]" maxlength="250" placeholder="Opción">';
        newtr = newtr +                     '<p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>';
        newtr = newtr +                 '</div>';                
        newtr = newtr +             '</div>';
        newtr = newtr +         '</td>';
        newtr = newtr +         '<td class="text-center vcenter" style="width: 90px;">';
        newtr = newtr +           '<button type="button" class="remove-opcion btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>';
        newtr = newtr +         '</td>';
        newtr = newtr +     '</tr>';
        //var numberNotChecked = $('#'+index_pregunta).find('.opcion-item input:checkbox:not(":checked")').length;
        var numberChecked = $('#'+index_pregunta).find('.opcion-item input:checkbox:checked').length;
        $('#'+justificar).show().prop("checked", false);
        $('#'+index_pregunta).find('.container-opciones').append(newtr);
        $("label[for='" + justificar + "']").show();
        $('#'+index_pregunta).find('.item-opcion').show(); 
        $('#'+index_pregunta).find('.pregunta').removeAttr('colspan',2);
        $( "#dynamic-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
            if(numberChecked > 0){
                $('#'+index_pregunta).find('.text-error-check').hide();
                $('#'+index_pregunta).find('.dynamicform_inner').removeAttr("style");
            } else {
                $('#'+index_pregunta).find('.text-error-check').show();
                $('#'+index_pregunta).find('.dynamicform_inner').css({'border':'2px solid #dd4b39','background-color':'white'});
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
   }});
```

Espero puedan apoyarme con estos problemas, no soy muy bueno usando javascript o jquery. Agradezco de ante mano su apoyo.